# Append cordova fileEntry objet to formData

Tags: php, ajax, cordova

I'm using cordova file plugin to get an object file get by cordova camera plugin

But I can't send it properly (as a input type file) to my php script.

I receive a `$_POST`  data instead of `$_FILES` data

I tried to append the result in formData, but it doesn't work :

```
 navigator.camera.getPicture(function createNewFileEntry(imageURI) {
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function success(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(success, fail);

    function success(file) {
        formData.append("image", file);
        console.log("data "+formData.get('featured_image')); // RETURN [object object] and not [file object]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found that I needed to create a blob file and read it with FileReader API.